# implicit conversion to fit existing constructors

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

My primary target is to have something like that:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock tp4{ 2013, 1,2,10,11,12,-1, 1234 };
```

So I created a class which covers `tm` objects like this:

```
struct Tm : std::tm {
    int tm_usecs; // [0, 999999] micros after the sec

    Tm(const int year, const int month, const int mday, const int hour,
       const int min, const int sec, const int usecs, const int isDST = -1)
        : tm_usecs{usecs} {
            tm_year = year - 1900; // [0, 60] since 1900
            tm_mon = month - 1;    // [0, 11] since Jan
            tm_mday = mday;        // [1, 31]
            tm_hour = hour;        // [0, 23] since midnight
            tm_min = min;          // [0, 59] after the hour
            tm_sec = sec;          // [0, 60] after the min
            //         allows for 1 positive leap second
            tm_isdst = isDST;      // [-1...] -1 for unknown, 0 for not DST,
            //         any positive value if DST.
        }
    template <typename Clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
             typename MicroSecond_t = std::chrono::microseconds>
                 auto to_time_point() const -> typename Clock_t::time_point {
                     auto tmp = *this; // hack to get it a const 
                     auto time_c = mktime(&tmp);
                     return Clock_t::from_time_t(time_c) + MicroSecond_t{tm_usecs};
                 }

    operator  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point () const
    {
        return to_time_point();
    }
};
```

OK, now I can write:

```
Tm ttt{2013, 1,2,10,11,12,-1, 1234};
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp3{ttt};
```

or

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp4{Tm{2013, 1,2,10,11,12,-1, 1234}};
```

EDIT:
The question pointed not only to the compile problem, because it simply was a typo, which you solved for me. Thanks and sorry for that stupid thing.

But:
Is there any way to get rid of the `Tm` inside the line of code? The problem is that:

An additional constructor can not be "introduced" without deriving from the clock type.
A conversion operator will not help as "on the fly" the type can not be seen by the compiler. So

```
 std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp4{{2013, 1,2,10,11,12,-1, 1234}};
```

can't work.

So the question goes to the point that there is maybe a hack to get the initializer list here to be accepted from the time_point. Maybe there could something be written with user defined deduction guides.

From Howards answer I see the idea to use a user defined literal to introduce the type which then later can be converted. Thanks for that!

Comment: Did you forget `::timepoint` for `tp4`, or did I misunderstand the question? The conversion operator you provide is for a `time_point`.

Comment: Clocks do not have a constructor which accepts arguments (it makes no sense, clock is a bundle of timepoint and now() function, basically), so your error is pretty obvious. Why are you trying to construct a clock like that? You have an example of constructing `time_point`, what are else is confusing?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OP already has an example of `time_point` working, I am very unsure at what OP is trying to achieve

Comment: @SergeyA I believe the problem with that example is that it's a two liner and OP wants a single line solution. This loops like a typing mistake to me where OP forgot to put `::time_point`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux may be... Let's see what OP says.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes simply a typo, edit this.

Comment: @SergeyA: Yes simply a typo. BTW: How to add two users to a comment :-)

Comment: @Klaus Your code seems to compile fine, after the edit : https://godbolt.org/g/G2nyKA

Answer (score 1):

`high_resolution_clock` has no portable relationship to human calendars.  For example on my platform (macOS) it measures the time since the computer booted up.

But you can aim for `system_clock`.  Though currently the epoch is unspecified, the de facto standard is that it measures time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (excluding leap seconds).  The epoch is currently specified in the [upcoming C++20 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4750.pdf).

[Here is a free, open-source library, which I have written,](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) that does what you're wanting to do with slightly different syntax:

```
#include "date/date.h"

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    system_clock::time_point tp = sys_days{2013_y/January/2} +
                                      10h + 11min + 12s + 1234us;
}
```

The date/time is specified in UTC.  If you need to specify the date/time with respect to a time zone, there is an [additional library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) to achieve that.

Both of these libraries are also in the [C++20 working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4750.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the idea to use a user defined literal in all that cases. My question used as an example the clock problem, but was meant more general to get a type conversion/construction introduced without deriving from the already given type like the time_point in my example.